# Are Angular directive controllers only meant for exposing publicly?

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-directive, lifecycle

From the AngularJS directive documentation:

> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other
>   directives. Otherwise use link.

Is this really the only case to use controllers inside directives?

what about some init functionality such as defaulting variable and scope values? should it generally go into link, unless publicly exposed?

Comment: contrary to answer below...more directives will have a `link` than will have a controller and most directives will have a link.

Answer (score -1):

I only use "link" when I have to implement some deeper DOM manipulation. Any "regular" component should use controllers. Basically the idea is to use "link" only when you don't have any other option as it's more involved and requires a deeper understanding of how Angular SJ works.

Comment: That is not what the documentation is saying at all and link can be used for lots of things that aren't dom related

Comment: I guess it just depends what you want to achieve. link is definitely not the easisest thing to master for someone who gets started with Angular.